# Generic way of checking if file in application is unsaved (AppleScript)

Tags: applescript

I'm using AppleScript to open files in Ableton Live, which is not officially scriptable. But I have at least managed to open files with it.

What I'm wondering is if it's possible in some generic way to check if the currently opened file within the application (it can only be one project open at a time in Ableton Live) has been modified, i. e. is unsaved? Or does it require the application in question to be officially scriptable?

Or is there otherwise any way of checking if a top menu item is disabled or not? I'm thinking that checking if the "Save project" menu item is clickable or not could work as a boolean for if the project has been saved or not.

Comment: Checking the state of a document in a non-scriptable app is not possible, but you can check the state of a menu item with GUI scripting and `System Events`.

Comment: Ah, that's something at least. Do you have examples on how this could be done? Another question: do you know if it's possible to "save as" the opened file to a specific path, or is that also something that would require the app to be scriptable?

Comment: 1) Please search for *AppleScript GUI scripting*. There are lots of examples. 2) It depends. It could be possible if the save dialog is a standard Cocoa dialog window.

Comment: 1) Yeah, sorry. I found some good examples! 2) It actually seems like it is a standard Cocoa dialog window. Can't really find any general approaches to this as the most examples I find are for specific apps. I'll continue looking but if you know any good resource, let me know!

Comment: You have to simulate pressing the keys ⇧⌘G in the save dialog box, wait until the sheet appears, set the `value` of the first `text field` to the (POSIX) path and press the OK button.

Comment: No, please don't go the GUI scripting route.  It's terrible, it's unreliable, it's lazy, and just shambolic. With a bit of thought and experimenting, you can almost certainly do it with actual scripting methods. If you're opening the file with AppleScript, then consider creating a log file that documents timestamps for files that are opened. At any time after this, use _System Events_ to read the `modification time`  to determine if the file has been written to. Additionally, commandline tools like `mdls` or `stat` reveal key information about the file. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ Generally, applications create a temporary file to work with actively, and write changes back to the original atomically to prevent data loss. Often, there'll be some swap files or temporary data stored somewhere like `~/Library/Application Support/` and `~/Library/Containers/`, so examine these folders for ones specific to Ableton. Also, look in `~/Library/Saved Application State/` for a data store that usually gets created when the app is open, and deleted upon successful closing. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ If the app is killed, the `.savedState` folder persists, and is used to reopen the app and whatever you were last working on. Inside a `.savedState` folder, there's a `windows.plist` file that contains bookmark data for each file that's open in the application. It'll be coded and can be uncoded but that takes more than AppleScript. However, many contain keyed values `"NSRepresentedURL"`, which are the paths to files open in the app. So there's a lot of breadcrumbs, you just need to be tenacious and thoughtful about it.

Comment: Thank you both for very valuable information!